# How to inherit in element in less like class stacking?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

we want to inherit from bootstraps `h1` in less using a mixin like

```
.btn2{ .btn; }
```

but instead want to use the `h1` element:

```
.h1_replace{ h1; }
```

Comment: As David F said in his answer, you cannot inherit by element type in LESS. Only classes or ids can be used as mixins.

Comment: Since Less 1.4.0 this statement doesn't hold true anymore, see thirteen's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that less supports that type of class inheritance. Instead you would likely have to redefine the h1 styling as a class and inherit that.

```
.h1 {
    /* copy h1 style here */
}

.h1_replace{ 
    .h1;
}
```

Though if you do this, you probably could just use the .h1 class throughout your code.

Comment: This seems to be the only and valid solution if you're stuck with a version of LESS < 1.4.0, otherwise you can nowadays just use the `:extend`.syntax w/o the need to refactor your LESS file structure.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an extend:

```
.h1_replace:extend(h1) {}
```

http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature